# Write to the beginning of file

Tags: file-io, julia

I've been trying to develop an algorithm which would at some point need to write results either to the beginning of a file, or to the end of it.

I'm trying to create a sorting algorithm which wouldn't use as much RAM as my files to be sorted are too big for my current specs. So for the cost of additional time, I would like to do this directly to file instead to RAM.

I know one can write files in Julia in this manner>

```
write(outfile,"A, B, C, D\n")
```

But I cannot seem to find how to write to the beginning of it.

Comment: Are you trying to just `overwrite` the data at the beginning of the file or `insert` new data without losing the data that is already there?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
s=open("test.txt", "a+");
write(s,"B");
write(s,"C");
position(s) # => 2
seekstart(s);
position(s) # => 0
write(s,"A"); # be careful you are overwriting B!
position(s) # => 1
close(s);
s=open("test.txt", "r");
read(s,Char) # => 'A'
read(s,Char) # => 'C' # we lost 'B'!
```

So if you like to prepend! something to a file stream, the above solution do not work.

```
cdata=readall(s);
seekstart(s);
write(s,prependdata);
write(s,cdata);
```

Comment: Thanks, this explains it all.

Answer (score 5):

You can use two files instead of one, as when you implement
[a deque with two stacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337278/how-to-implement-a-dequeue-using-two-stacks):

- To append data, append to the first file: it will store the tail of the data.
- To prepend data, *append* to the second file: it will store the head of the data, but in reverse order.
- When you need the data in a single file (probably just once, at the end of your algorithm), reverse the lines in the second file and concatenate the files.

Answer (score 0):

<del>There is no way to prepend data to a disk file.</del>

There is no "insert mode" when writing to a file stream.

If your files are too big for your current specs, I suggest using database instead.

If the size of the dataset is not an issue, you can always read the content of existing file into memory, prepend the new data to it, and then overwrite the whole file. It does not actually save RAM though, as the whole dataset still needs to be read into memory every time.

Comment: Is there a specific reason as to why it is not possible? Excuse me if it is obvious, I am not expert in this area.

Comment: @sdgawerzswer It’s not directly supported in the low level.
(In many file systems, files are stored in blocks.
If you decide to insert some data at the start of the file, data in the rest of the file needs to be moved otherwhere, which can be an inefficient operation as disk I/O is much more slower than memory)

Comment: @sdgawerzswer 
Of course you can always read the existing file into memory, manipulate the data in memory and rewrite the whole file. It does not actually "save memory" though. Using a database is an nicer option IMHO.

Comment: But database still needs lots of space doesn't it? I man what difference does it make if I create an additional database if the algorithm still runs iteratively (it is not possible to read whole database during runtime).

Comment: @sdgawerzswer Yes database needs lots of disk space, since the data needs to be stored anyway. Simply speaking it's just a better managed (and more complicated) file system. Assuming that you have enough disk space and limited RAM, using a database might helps. But I'm not saying it's definitely the right way to go -- It all depends on your requirements.